# Presentational - Container (or Smart - Dumb) component pattern with Vuex

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex

How do you recommend to handle the Presentational - Container (or Smart - Dumb) component pattern with Vuex? Should the Presentational (or Dumb) components emit events to the parent or call Vuex actions? Imagine having a complex component structure where a Container (or Smart) component has many nested Presentational components. The nested event emission (eg, 4 levels) can be difficult to handle and requires a lot of repetitive code, but, on the other hand, a Presentational component that calls actions, does not seem very presentational to me. What about using an event bus? I know it is not recommended, and this is why I would like to read your recommendations.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend not to overthink it:) I'd go for sending events from Presentational component if it's one level nesting. If it's more - call vuex action.